# Finding the expected value of a variable using double integration in polar coordinates.

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, elementary-probability

This is a statistics problem, but it requires integration. And I'm getting a little lost in the problem because there are multiple variables involved when you switch over to polar coordinates, and I feel like I'm making many mistakes (it's been about 1-2 years since I last took calculus).

**Question**:

[image]

I first need to find the marginal probability of X, which is:

$f_X(x) = \int^{\infty }_{-\infty}f(x,y)dy$

I know the following:

$x = acos(\theta), y=asin(\theta), r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = a$

Okay, so we have:

$f_X(x) = \int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{1}{\pi a^2}acos(\theta)d\theta = \int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{1}{\pi a}cos(\theta)d\theta = \frac{1}{\pi a^2}sin(\theta) = 0$

So then the expected value of $X$ is:

$E(X) = \int^{-\infty}_{\infty} x \times f_X(x) dx$

Which would be zero? The book says zero is the correct answer, but I'm not sure if the steps I did here are correct or if I arrived at that answer coincidentally.

Also, if $f_X(x)$ were nonzero and I actually had to proceed with the integration, what would the limits have been? From $0$ to $2\pi$ again?

Comment: It's true that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is 0, you can see it reasoning with the simmetry of the random variable, but your calculation is wrong and you can understand it because $f_X$ you found is not a probability density. You tried to calculate an integral in $dy$ using a change of variables for both $x$ and $y$, that was the initial mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer cannot be correct as the marginal density you found does not integrate to $1$. You need to be careful with the bounds of integration. The set $\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq a^2\}$ is the closed disk of radius $a$ about $(0,0)$. Hence
$$
f_X(x)=\int_{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\frac{1}{\pi a^2}\,dy
=\frac{1}{\pi a^2}2\sqrt{a^2-x^2};\quad -a\leq x\leq a.
$$
Hence
$$
EX=\int_{-a}^axf_X(x)\,dx=\int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{\pi a^2}2x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx
=0
$$
since the integrand is odd.

Comment: "since the integrand is odd." I lost you at that part. Could you please clarify how one would integrate this? u-substitution with u = a^2 - x^2?

Comment: If $f$ is an odd function, then $\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,dx=0$ for $a>0$.

Comment: Still don't understand, could you offer an alternative explanation that doesn't rely on "oddness"? I don't know what that means.